# Why shouldn't I have circular dependencies in my gradle build?

Tags: performance, gradle, optimization, build, mmo

Is there a performance impact with having circular dependencies? With Gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies in gradle are discouraged to avoid confusion. When it comes to circular dependencies, you should keep the following in mind:

- Gradle does **not** support circular dependencies within individual configurations
- Gradle **can** support two or more configurations depending on each other, unless

  - There is a **compile** or **implementation** circular dependency

In general, these restrictions limit any use case of circular dependencies, and it's highly recommended to refactor them out of your project instead.